# How to avoid duplicates of form fields and validations of forms angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular.

I am building a application which have contact form, when you are click submit button, if it required show that error message. there are another option called new row button when I click that button showing same error message in the field also.

Expected result - validation does not show with newly added row

Actual result - once a row triggered with a validation it shows in newly adding rows too

My current code is given below.

```
public checkFieldValidity(field:any,isInRoot:boolean){
    debugger
    let isDomRequired:boolean = false
    if(field.programmableId != null && field.programmableId != undefined && field.programmableId != "" && isInRoot == true){
        var domElement = document.getElementById(field.programmableId)
        if(domElement != null && domElement != undefined){
            isDomRequired = domElement.hasAttribute('required')
        }
    }
    var property = field.formFieldPropertyJson;
    if(property != null && typeof field.formFieldPropertyJson == 'string'){
        property = JSON.parse(property)
    }

    let formValidationResult:FormValidationResult = new FormValidationResult()
    if(field.type == 'file' && field.isFileUploadingInProgress){
        formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
        formValidationResult.errorMessage = "File uploading in progress!!!"
    }
    else if(field.type == 'customSection'){
        debugger
        for(let dynamicSectionField of field.dynamicSectionFields){
            if(dynamicSectionField.type == 'file' && dynamicSectionField.isFileUploadingInProgress){
                formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
                formValidationResult.errorMessage = "File uploading in progress!!!"
                break
            }
            else if (property.required == true && (dynamicSectionField.value == null || dynamicSectionField.value == "")) {
                formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
                formValidationResult.errorMessage = "Empty form! Please enter relevant values"
                break
            }
        }
    }
    else if(field.type == 'number'){

      if (property.required == true && (field.value == null || field.value == "")) {
        formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
        formValidationResult.errorMessage = "Empty form! Please enter relevant values"
    }
        if(property != null && field.value != null && property.min != null && property.max != null){
            var min = parseInt(property.min)
            var max = parseInt(property.max)
            var val = field.value
            if(!(val >= min && val <=max)){
                formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
                formValidationResult.errorMessage = field.name+" field is not in the range. "+min+" and "+max
            }
        }
    }
    else if(field.type == 'UserPicker' && property.required){
        if(field.value != null && field.value.length > 0){
            var inputsParsed = JSON.parse(field.value)
            if(inputsParsed.length == 0){
                formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
                formValidationResult.errorMessage = field.name+" is required"
            }
        }
        else{
            formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
            formValidationResult.errorMessage = field.name+" is required"
        }
    }
    else if ((property.required == true || isDomRequired == true) && (field.value == null || field.value == "")) {
        formValidationResult.isFormValid = false
        debugger
        console.log("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS")
        formValidationResult.errorMessage = "Empty form! Please enter relevant values"
    }
    return formValidationResult
}
```

[image: Check FIle]

Simply I want stop this message repeat Please help me

Comment: please provide your HTML also, and if you provide a stackblitz link it would be more helpful

Comment: @HirasHarisin my one i create the validation.ts file for this this source code in my validation file there  are no html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior. You can enable error handling on blur only:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  exampleField: ['initial value', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }],
});
```